# I see data comes correctly but for some reason recycler dont show images with glide

Tags: android

Im making api call. And see that data comes correctly. But recycler does not show it properly
. One detail is it happens after `more` button been clicked. So items suppose to be updated. First time on open it shows everything correctly. As you can see from the image example

[image]

The code

```
  moreButton.setOnClickListener {
        val nextPage = page++
        val apiInterface = ApiInterface.create().getMemes(nextPage.toString())
        apiInterface.enqueue(object : Callback<MemeResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<MemeResponse>?, response: Response<MemeResponse>?) {
                response?.body()?.data?.apply {
                    adapter.updateList(this)
                    this.forEach {
                        Log.d("listtesting", "${it.name} ${it.image}")
                    }
                }
                Log.d("testLogs", "OnResponse Success ${call.toString()} ")
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<MemeResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.d("testLogs", "onFailure : ${t?.message}")
            }
        })
    }
```

Adapter code

```
    package com.mywebsite.memegeneratorexample

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide

class CustomAdapter (private var mList: List<Data>, private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_item_name)
        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_item_image)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_meme, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.name.text = mList[position].name
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(mList[position].image)
            .into(holder.imageView)
    }

    fun updateList(newList: List<Data>){
        mList = newList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mList.size
    }
}
```

Comment: put a listener on Glide to see if the image is being rendered without any errors.

Comment: @SubhasmithThapa how to do that?

Comment: Please go through this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2945946-glide-tutorial-for-android-getting-started)